# Combinatorics Forming a word from set of Alphaphets

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A sequence of 15 random draws, one at a time with replacement, is made from the set { A,B,C ...,X,Y,Z } of the English Alphabet(26 Alphabets in total). What is the probability that the string "UNIVERSITY" occurs as a block in the sequence?

These are some steps I thought of, but I'm stuck and don't know how to continue.

1) Find the total number of sequences possibly drawn which is $26^{15}$

The answer given is $\frac{6}{26^{10}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can imagine the string "University" as a super element S.

Thus you have 5 places, where there can be any letter.

$Sxxxxx$

And there are 6 possible arrangements:

$Sxxxxx$

$xSxxxx$

$xxSxxx$

$xxxSxx$

$xxxxSx$

$xxxxxS$

The "x´s" can be one of the 26 letters: $26^5$.

Altogether you have $26^5\cdot 6$ arrangements for the given conditions.

Now you can divide the number by the total number of sequences.